# Own game created. Else branch is not executed after Game Over

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

I created a small game with Pygame Zero and the MU IDE. The player has to click (collect) as many bananas as possible in a certain time. Each time a banana is collected, a new banana appears at random position.

After the time has elapsed, a new screen will appear with information on how many bananas have been collected. For this I created an If Else statement, but the Else branch is not executed by the program (Except for reducing the time by 1 second and close of game window). I don't know why. Does anyone have an idea why the Else branch is not executed?

```py
from random import randint 
import time
import pygame

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 800
score = 0
time_left = 10

banana = Actor("banana")
monkey = Actor("monkey")

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill("white")
    banana.draw()
    monkey.draw()
    screen.draw.text("Number of bananas collected: " + str(score),      color = "black", topleft=(10,10))
    screen.draw.text("Time: " + str(time_left), color = "black", topleft=(10,50))

def place_banana():
    banana.x = randint(125, 790)
    banana.y = randint(186, 790)
    monkey.x = 50
    monkey.y = 740

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global score
    if banana.collidepoint(pos): 
        score = score + 1 
        place_banana()

def update_time_left():
    global time_left
    if time_left:  # wenn Zeit > 0 Sekunden ist
        time_left = time_left - 1
    else:  
        screen.fill("pink")  # code is not executed
        game_over() 

place_banana() 
clock.schedule_interval(update_time_left, 1.0)

def game_over():
    screen.fill("pink") # code is not executed
    global time_left
    message = ("Ende. Number of bananas collected")   # code is not  executed
    time_left = 0
    time.sleep(5.5)
    quit()
```

Comment: It might help if you rephrased your question. Looks like your else statement works, but screen.fill("pink") does not work as intended. Rephrasing will get you more direct and relevant help.

Comment: Of course the code is executed, but between `screen.fill("pink")` and `quit()` the display is never updated.

Comment: I don't know exactly how `pygame` works, but `if time_left` is truthy. That means if the clock doesn't perfectly hit `0` on the loop, `else` will never execute. Ie, if it goes from time 1 to time -0.00001, then you will never exit the game. It might be better to do if `time_left > 0: ... else: ...` to explicitly exclude negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the code is executed, but you cant "see" the result on the display, because after `screen.fill("pink")` (and before `time.sleep(5.5)`) the display is not updated.
You've to update the display by [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) and to handle the events by (e.g) [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) after the display is filled in pink.

```py
def game_over():

    screen.fill("pink")
    # [...] draw something else (e.g. some text)    

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.event.pump()

    time.sleep(5.5)
    quit()
```

Comment: Thankyou! Yes i forgot to update display. As a beginner I don't think about all things. I changed it and now it is working!